# When Converting Next App to Typescript, JSX is shown with errors but runs fine in the browser

Tags: typescript, jsx, next.js

When I convert my Next App from `JS` to `TSX`, for some reason the `JSX` in my `TSX` file is underlined and showing errors. But it runs fine in the browser. I am unsure why this is true. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Below are some images of my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UlcA.png), [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUTfN.png), and [tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWCPk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't `import React from "react";`. And that means these HTML elements are JSX.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this did not work. I tried "import React from 'react';' and "import * as React from 'react';' and both did not solve the problem. Is there anything that may be issue?